# Hide report footer on second page in Crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to show report page footer on only first page and not on second page.I mean hide page footer on second page not suppress.Because of suppress I have facing space problem on second page.So, give me answer about these.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! your question doesn't give a lot of detail... to get better answers, you should give examples of what you've already tried, and a sample if possible.

Comment: Suppress should work; if it doesn't work, you need to explain more clearly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Crystal Reports (I'm using CR 2008 Version 12.0.0) you can achieve this by doing the following:

1. Put your footer text in the page footer
2. Open the section expert and put `WhilePrintingRecords; PageNumber > 1` in the Suppress Formula field.
3. Check "Suppress Blank Section"
4. Check "Clamp Page Footer"

That should only show the footer on the first page and eliminate blank spaces on subsequent pages.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Thanks for your answer about question but i am not found Clamp Page footer option in CR2008 and Version is 9.Suggest me where these is option.

Answer (score 0):

if you checked "Clamp Page Footer", the second and last page's height will be cut to shrink!